# Jest: spyOn test failing even though (async) function is executing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jestjs, supertest

I'm trying to spyOn an async function that's called within a submodule. This is something I've done many times before, so I can't work out why it's failing! Here's the (simplified) code:

routes.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { fetchSamples } = require('./controllers.js');

router.get('/fetch-samples', fetchSamples);
```

controllers.js

```
const { fetchSamplesFromDb } = require('./services');

exports.fetchSamples = (req, res) => {
  const data = await fetchSamplesFromDb(req.query.params);
  res.status(200).json(data);
};
```

services.js

```
exports.fetchSamplesFromDb = async params => {
  console.log('I get called!');
  const x = await xyz; // Other stuff....
};
```

And the failing test:

```
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../app.js'); // express web server
const services = require('../services.js');

it('responds with 200 when successful', async () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(services, 'fetchSample');
  const response = await request(app).get('/fetch-samples');
  expect(response.status).toBe(200); // PASSES
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled(); // FAILS
});
```

I can't work out why the spy isn't called. I've wondered if it's because it's async, but I haven't been able to get the test to pass. Would really appreciate some pointers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you `require` the module under test, before mocking use the `jest.spyOn()` method, the `services` module is also required and deconstructed with the original `fetchSamplesFromDB` method.

It's late when you use `jest.spyOn()` method to mock `fetchSamplesFromDB` method in test case function. You can use the service method like this:

```js
const services = require('./services');

exports.fetchSamples = async (req, res) => {
  const data = await services.fetchSamplesFromDb(req.query.params);
  res.status(200).json(data);
};
```

In this way, `jest.spyOn(services, 'fetchSamplesFromDb')` will work.

Comment: You got it @slideshowp2! Thanks a bunch!!